# 6×6 Matrix Exponential using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function, matrix-calculus, cayley-hamilton

For the $6×6$ matrix
$$P=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\                         
-1& 0 & 0 & 4 & 2 & 0 \\              
0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\            
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\          
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\         
0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\                  
\end{pmatrix}
$$
What is the answer to $e^{Pt}$ using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem?
The characteristic polynomial is $x^6$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions. Also, it's better to include more of your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)

Answer (score 3):

From  Cayley-Hamilton we get $P^6=0,$ hence $P^n=0$ for $n \ge 6.$ Then

$$e^{Pt}= \sum_{k=0}^5\frac{t^kP^k}{k!}.$$

Comment: How would you get the final answer of e^pt from using this formula, after subbing back in the matrices?